# Huawei Matebook D14, Wi-Fi visible, but not workable

Tags: fedora, wifi, huawei

I've been trying to install Fedora 34 Workstation on my Huawei Matebook D14 laptop. So, the problem is that wifi can show me other networks, but fails to connect each one of them.
Network card is Realtek RTL8822CE Wireless Adapter.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you specify how it "fails to connect"? Is there an error message, and if so, which one?

Comment: Hello! No, there are no exact error message. I just type in correct password, but wi-fi still does not connect to the internet

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same error while installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my Huawei matebook D14.
I think leaving the answer here can help others late:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw88
```

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309905/rtl8822ce-wireless-adapter-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-18-04?newreg=1dd6e786e1b54c799134742a6c22c8bc